# How to return values ​from an asynchronous function that is executed in a thread in python?

Tags: python-3.x, asynchronous, websocket, python-asyncio, python-multithreading

I am new to asynchronous functions and threads, and I am trying to return a series of values ​​obtained from a Web socket to pass to another thread where synchronous code is executing. In the code, I also use a multi Web socket approach. Below I show you the code:

```
"""
This code is designed to run an asynchronous loop
with asyncio in a separate thread. This allows mixing
a synchronous code with an asynchronous one. 
"""

import asyncio
from datetime import datetime
from threading import Thread
import websockets
from typing import Tuple, List, Iterable
import json
import time

URLS = [
    "wss://stream.binance.com:9443/ws/xrpusdt@kline_1m",
    "wss://stream.binance.com:9443/ws/btcusdt@kline_1m",
]

def start_background_loop(loop: asyncio.AbstractEventLoop):
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
    loop.run_forever()

async def IndividualSubscription(url: str):
    """An individual subscription to each WebSocket is created"""
    async with websockets.connect(url) as websocket:
        data = await websocket.recv()
        data = json.loads(data)

        print('\n', data)
           
        return data

async def Subscriptions(URLS: Iterable[str]):
    """All concurrent tickets are subscribed and all are combined
        in a single coroutine."""

    while True:
        task = [asyncio.create_task(SuscripcionIndividual(url)) for url in URLS]
        
        # All tasks are run in parallel
        await asyncio.gather(*tareas)
        #return tareas

def main():
    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    t = Thread(target=start_background_loop, args=(loop,), daemon=True)
    t.start()

    task = asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(Suscripciones(URLS), loop)
    for i in task.result():
        print(f"{i}")

    #return tareas

def function():
        for i in range(100):
            print("This is out of asynchronous ", i)
            time.sleep(1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
    T2 = Thread(target=function,)
    T2.start()
```

I tried to just put `return` to the async code, but by doing this the async loop only runs once and not continuously as I would expect. Also, I've tried the method `.result()` over `.create_task()` . Is it possible to return values ​​from an asynchronous function?

Comment: Your main method should wait for the thread to finish using ```T2.join()``` after it calls ```T2.start()``` and to get the return value from your ```async``` function use ```r = await f()```

Comment: For example ```result = await asyncio.gather(...)``` or ```return await asyncio.gather(...)```

Answer (score 0):

If you want interoperability between synchronous and asynchronous code you need to design some communication mechanism that won't block the thread running async code. Queues are commonly used for communication between threads, [janus](https://github.com/aio-libs/janus) library implements queues compatible with threads running async code, it does so by exposing sync queue interface to sync code and async queue interface to async code.

Your code is a little chaotic, so I cleaned it up just to show communication between sync thread (main thread) and async thread (background thread running asyncio loop)

```py
import asyncio
from datetime import datetime
from threading import Thread
import websockets
from typing import Tuple, List, Iterable
import json
import time
import janus # pip install janus

URLS = [
    "wss://stream.binance.com:9443/ws/xrpusdt@kline_1m",
    "wss://stream.binance.com:9443/ws/btcusdt@kline_1m",
]

def start_background_loop(loop: asyncio.AbstractEventLoop):
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
    loop.run_forever()

async def IndividualSubscription(url: str):
    """An individual subscription to each WebSocket is created"""
    async with websockets.connect(url) as websocket:
        return json.loads(await websocket.recv())

async def Subscriptions(URLS: Iterable[str], results: asyncio.Queue):
    """All concurrent tickets are subscribed and all are combined
        in a single coroutine."""
    while True:
        tasks = [asyncio.create_task(SuscripcionIndividual(url)) for url in URLS]
        for task in await asyncio.gather(*tasks):
            await results.put(task.result())


def async_main(results: asyncio.Queue):
    asyncio.run(Subscriptions(URLS, results))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    results = janus.Queue(100) # max size of 100
    async_thread = Thread(target=async_main, args=(results.async_q,))
    async_thread.daemon = True # exit if main thread exits
    async_thread.start()
    while True:
        print(f"[sync thread] got result from async thread: {results.sync_q.get()}")
```

Comment: can this be done with vanilla Python?  working on a SOC and don't have the ability to use pip.  :P  in other words, is this doable **without** `Janus`?

Comment: Janus is a small library and has no external dependency, so just copy and paste their code into your project. Check their license to make sure it's compatible with your code.

Comment: alright!  that's great news.  thank you very much.